Забинденые клавиши работают с побочным эффектом в nvim
Осваиваю nvim. Потихоньку собираю свой init.vim. Сначала стандартные настройки, потом сочетания клавиш, устанавливаю плагины и тд. И в определенный момент, моя забинденная на F2 команда :w выполняется совместно с перемещением курсора на 12 символов вперед.
Началось с того, что я так же настраивал всё, добавлял, а потом заметил, что все вот эти клавиши
nmap <F2> :w<CR>            " Сохранить файл
nmap <F3> :q!<CR>           " Выйти без сохранения
nmap <F4> : wq<CR>          " Сохранить и выйти

при нажатии вызывают вставку пробела после курсора. Тоесть нажал F2, он пробел вставил и сохранил. Нажал F4 он пробел вставил, сохранил, вышел. Открываю файл заново - сохранилось с пробелом. Я начал заново init.vim делать. Опять делал, делал, и в итоге вот с перемещением курсора началось. Все строки кроме стандартных настроек set закомментил, плагины тоже, выполныл :PlugClean, но при F2 никуда не пропало это перемещение на 12 символов. Как отследить, откуда берётся дополнительная команда?
Прилагаю полностью конфиг в том виде, в каком сейчас он есть
""""""""""""""ОСНОВНЫЕ НАСТРОЙКИ
set number
set relativenumber
set cursorline
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set laststatus=2
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set encoding=utf-8
set fileformat=unix
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set splitbelow
set splitright
set equalalways
set hlsearch
set nocompatible
set sts=4
set cursorcolumn
filetype on
syntax on
set cursorline
set nowrap
set history=1000
set termguicolors

""""""ПЛАГИНЫ

call plug#begin()
"Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'           " Какая то хуйня
"Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'      " Строка состояния
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'          " Дерево файлов
"Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'           " але какое то
"Plug 'powerman/vim-plugin-ruscmd'   " Команды в русской раскладк 
"Plug 'solvedbiscuit71/vim-autopair' " Автоматическое написание парных символов 
"Plug 'junegunn/fzf'                 " Поиск файлов
"Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'             " 
"Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'         " Работа с комментариями
"Plug 'wincent/indent-blankline.nvim' " Отступы 
"Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vi            m', { 'on': 'JediClearCache' }  "Пайтон language server protocol. Автокомплит
"Plug 'voldikss/vim-floatemn'        " Сессия терминала в нвим
"  Plug 'dstein64/nvim-scrollview'     " По лоса прокрутки
call plug#end()

""""""Автозапуск NERDTree
"autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p
"autocmd BufEnter * if tabpagenr('$') == 1 && winnr('$') == 1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | call feedkeys(":quit\<CR>:\<BS>") | endif
" Close th    e tab if NERDTree is the only window remaining in it.
"autocmd BufEnter * if winnr('$') ==                         1 && exists('b:NERDTree') && b:NERDTree.isTabTree() | call feedkeys(":quit\<CR>:\<BS>") | endif
" Open the existing NERDTree on each new tab.
"autocmd BufWinEnter * if &buftype != 'quickfix' && getcmdwintype() == '' | silent NERDTreeMirror | endif
""""""Jedi-vim
"F8 запускает Python Language Server Protocol
"autocmd FileType python map <F8> :JediClearCache<CR>
"autocmd FileType python imap <F8> <ESC>:JediClearCache<CR>a
"""""""""""""ГОРЯЧИЕ КЛАВИШИ
nmap <F2> :w<CR>            " Сохранить файл
"nmap <F3> :q!<CR>           " Выйти без сохранения
"nmap <F4> : wq<CR>          " Сохранить и выйти
                        
"nmap <C-h> :wincmd h<CR>    " Переключить окно влево
"nmap <C-j> :wincmd j<CR>    " Переключить окно вниз
"nmap <C-k> :wincmd k<CR>    " Переключить окно вверх
"nmap <C-l> :wincmd l<CR>    " Переключить окно вправо
"noremap <Enter> o<ESC>
"noremap <Space> a<Space><ESC>
"inoremap jk <ESC>
"nnoremap ,<Space> :nohlsearch<CR>
"autocmd FileType sh,python map <buffer> <F5> :w<CR>:!chmod ug+x <C-R>=shellescape(@%, 1)<CR> && sh -c ./<C-R>=shellescape(@%, 1)<CR><CR> autocmd FileType sh,python imap <buffer> <F5> <esc>:w<CR>:!chmod ug+x <C-R>=shellescape(@%, 1)<CR> && sh -c ./<C-R>=shellescape(@%, 1)<CR><CR>


каждый пробел после :w<CR> перемещает курсор вправо на один символ

ааа, это изза неправильно поставленного символа " ?)) но даже если бы я обратил на это внимание, то всё равно не подумал бы, что здесь играет это роль, поидее пробелы после , тоесть как после нажатия на ентер
